# SQL server 2012 tables issue, sysdate and to_date issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-applications

I have two issues while trying to create tables.

For *****sysdate****** it says invalid column name
for ***TO_DATE('01-JAN-2008','DD-MON-YYYY')));*****  it says TO_DATE is not a reconigized built-in function name.

^ both are in the Table Invoice.

This is using SQL SERVER 2012

```
CREATE TABLE VENDOR(
V_CODE          INTEGER     NOT NULL    UNIQUE,
V_NAME          VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
V_CONTACT       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
V_AREACODE      CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
V_PHONE         CHAR(8)     NOT NULL,
V_STATE         CHAR(2)     NOT NULL,
v_ORDER         CHAR(1)     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (V_CODE));

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(
P_CODE          VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
P_DESCRIPT      VARCHAR(35)     NOT NULL,
P_INDATE        DATE            NOT NULL,
P_QOH           SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
P_MIN           SMALLINT        NOT NULL,
P_PRICE         DECIMAL(8,2)    NOT NULL,
P_DISCOUNT      DECIMAL(5,2)    NOT NULL,
V_CODE          INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (P_CODE),
FOREIGN KEY(V_CODE) REFERENCES VENDOR ON UPDATE CASCADE);


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
CUS_CODE            DECIMAL         PRIMARY KEY,
CUS_LNAME           VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
CUS_FNAME           VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
CUS_INITIAL         CHAR(1),            
CUS_AREACODE        CHAR(3)         DEFAULT '615'       NOT NULL,
                                                        CHECK(CUS_AREACODE IN ('615','713','931')),
CUS_PHONE           CHAR(8)         NOT NULL,
CUS_BALANCE         DECIMAL(9,2)        DEFAULT 0.00,
CONSTRAINT CUS_UI1 UNIQUE (CUS_LNAME, CUS_FNAME));


CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
INV_NUMBER      DECIMAL     PRIMARY KEY,
CUS_CODE        DECIMAL     NOT NULL REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUS_CODE),
INV_DATE        DATE        DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT INV_CK1 CHECK (INV_DATE > TO_DATE('01-JAN-2008','DD-MON-YYYY')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

- the function to get the current system date and time is called `SYSDATETIME()` in T-SQL/SQL Server (not `sysdate`)
- the way to convert a string to a `date` or `datetime` in T-SQL/SQL Server is using `CAST` or `CONVERT` (not `TO_DATE` - there is no such function in T-SQL)

Use something like

```
SELECT CAST('01-JAN-2008' AS DATE)
```

or something like that (it's highly dependent on your language/date format settings in SQL Server whether it'll work or not). If you need to specify a specific format, you can use `CONVERT` which allows you to use one of the many predefined formats (see [relevant details in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)).

If that's still not enough - SQL Server **2012** has a new function called `PARSE` which allows you to specify any arbitrary date format that your string is formatted in. Again, see the [relevant MSDN documentation for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx).

The best thing is to avoid converting dates back and forth to and from strings if ever possible, and in your case, this should be easily doable! Just use:

```
INV_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATETIME() NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT INV_CK1 CHECK (INV_DATE > '20080101');
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and amazing explanation. I now know SYSDATETIME() is the correct use. I realized I might need to check my format settings in SQL Server. I did not know it was required. I changed my code to CONSTRAINT INV_CK1 CHECK (INV_DATE > '20080101');   

and it worked perfectly.